# Groovy/Grails: How do I make my datePicker blank or null by default instead of showing today's date?

Tags: grails, date, groovy, null

That is basically my question. It is showing me today's date and not a blank or null or '' date, even if I put null or '' it runs perfectly but keeps showing me today's date, not a blank dropdown box. So I want to change the default to being blank when the gsp loads, not with today's date.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The usage of the attribute `default` is not documented in the Grails documentation but its functionality can be extracted from the implementation. Use the attribute `default="none"`to stop the datePicker from using the current date and provide an empty text as the noSelection value:

```
<g:datePicker default="none" noSelection="['':'']" />
```

More information about the attribute `noSelection` can be found in the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/datePicker.html).